# Why does foreach in C++ can't traverse the first element?

Tags: c++, foreach

In `foreach` loop, it seems the first element is not traversed and the 6th element `num[5]` is traversed which is undefined.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int num[5];
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) num[i] = i + 1;
    for (auto i : num) cout << num[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

expected output: 1,2,3,4,5

output: 2,3,4,5,0

Comment: It should be `cout<<i<<" "`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `i` is not an index, but the value, you should replace:

```
for (auto i:num)cout<<num[i]<<" ";
```

with

```
for (auto i:num)cout<< i <<" ";
```

Then you get the proper output `1 2 3 4 5`